# RRDTool - fetching data based on several RRD'S

Tags: rrdtool, rrd

Is it possible to fetch data by RRDTool based on several RRD DBs, for example getting values which are sum of all values fecthed from each RRD?

Answer (score 7):

the fetch function deals only with one rrd at a time, but in graph and xport you can pull in data from multiple rrd files. You can then mix and match them to your hearts content using CDEF and VDEF. I you just want the data and no grpah, simply use PRINT to get the data out.

hth
tobi